How to edit alpha transparency for new GLTF models programatically
I want to change the transparency of a model's visual geometries (iiwa 7).Before the switch to GLTF files, I was able to do it using the following logic:
for geometry_id in visual_geometry_ids:
            old_props = scene_graph.model_inspector().GetIllustrationProperties(
                geometry_id
            )
            new_props = IllustrationProperties(old_props)
            old_rgba = old_props.GetProperty("phong", "diffuse")
            new_props.UpdateProperty(
                group_name="phong",
                name="diffuse",
                value=Rgba(
                    r=old_rgba.r(),
                    g=old_rgba.g(),
                    b=old_rgba.b(),
                    a=new_alpha,
                ),
            )
            scene_graph.AssignRole(
                source_id=plant.get_source_id(),
                geometry_id=geometry_id,
                properties=new_props,
                assign=RoleAssign.kReplace,
            )

However, the illustration properties of the new GLTF models only contain a "__default__" group with no properties.

Oops. I'd like to more fully understand your need.
Given that you're editing IllustrationProperties, you're interested in its appearance in meshcat (and this isn't about rendering in a simulated sensor).
Presumably, you want to selectively edit the transparency of certain objects. In other words, the ability to make all illustration geometries less opaque in the meshcat window is insufficiently targeted for you?
What you might do, is make calls to set opacity properties directly on meshcat. I'll defer details until after I get further elaboration.

All of these are correct.
I had a look at setting it directly on meshcat and found SetProperty that allows me to set an object's RGBA values. However, there does not seem to be an equivalent GetProperty method for getting the existing color and keeping it the same.
For setting the property in meshcat, I will need to know the meshcat path. Is it possible to obtain the meshcat path associated with a GeometryId?

One of your challenges in getting the meshcat path depends on whether you're using meldis or MeshcatVisualizer. Their paths will differ. The names of the paths will change. It would probably be good to add an API to MeshcatVisualizer that can take a GeometryId and return a path name. Would you like to submit an issue?
Short-term, for a specific model/visualizer, you could inspect meshcat and infer some rules, a bit brittle, but you'd be up and running.

I like that idea. I will open an issue.

Thanks for the issue. I've added all the various important tags to it.

The good news is that, as long as you can identify the path of the object you want to change, changing only its opacity (while leaving its original color -- or complex textures -- intact), is super easy.
meshcat->SetProperty("path/to/my/thing/<object>", "opacity", alpha);
meshcat->SetProperty("path/to/my/thing/<object>", "modulated_opacity", alpha);

The first line sets the target to being a uniform opacity (the alpha value). The second lines modulates the original opacity -- the new opacity is the original opacity times alpha. You can choose to set either value interchangably -- meshcat remembers what the original opacity was and updates the current opacity based on the last flavor of opacity that got set.
Do not forget to append /<object> to the end of your path. The opacity you want to set belongs to the underlying 3D object, so you must call that out specifically.

IMO we should also add "modulated_opacity" as an IllustrationProperties, so that users can set it in SceneGraph and have all displays reflect the transparancy.  But for now, yes this is the best approach.

That's a great idea. Any thoughts on having that survive the path through meldis?

Same as diffuse_map -- upgrade the load message to carry json illustration properties.
